# Value categories with jqplot in a bar chart

Tags: javascript, charts, bar-chart, jqplot

I am trying to draw a chart with jqplot for a web application showing statistics about the other applications, especially showing the number of uses of those.

On typical data aray would look like this

```
[["app1", 60],["app2", 222],["app3", 73]]
```

My problem is that I wish to separate them as categories like

- category 1 : app1, app2
- category 2 : app3

I can't use jqplot series because they group the bars (app1 would show right next to app3), I only need them to be color-grouped by category :

- app 1 in blue
- app 2 in blue
- app 3 in green
- etc.

And also have the legend showing me those categories with associated colors.
I have done some heavy searching and have yet to find a functionality for this kind of feature.

I could maybe do all of this manually with javascript but it seems difficult.

Is there a way I could do this ?

Comment: This functionality will not be available by default. I had similar cases and I solved them by downloading jqPlot source code and making changes myself.

Comment: Yes, I will probably have to do that in the end.. Not looking forward to it !